# Changing numeric values to alpha values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

=TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(ISERROR(MATCH({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},B2:B10,0)),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},""))

I was given the above formula to let me know what numbers from 1 - 9 were remaining for Rows (above is for Row B2:J10. This is for my Sudoku game and I have converted the Sudoku game to play only letters from A - I and need to change the textjoin formula to ABC;s. I tried replacing  the numbers with a,b,c, etc but doesn't work, so suppose the textjoin needs to be changed to accept alpha characters. Everything I switched over works except this one formula. and keep in mind I am not the expert on VBA or formulas, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can use `CHAR`. `CHAR(65)` = `A` (uppercase). Count up from there for following letters. `CHAR(97)` = `a` (lowercase).

Answer (score 0):

### Solved: (again! ☻) ♣

*(Key updates below)*

**Options**

1. Use *choose* (Office 365+)
2. OR: use char()

**Functions**

1 - Choose function:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(ISERROR(MATCH({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},b2:b10,0)),CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","I","j","k"),""))
```

[image: Choose function]

2 - Char():

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(ISERROR(MATCH({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},B2:B10,0)),CHAR({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}+96),""))
```

[image: Ta: @Nicholas Hunter]

### KEY UPDATES:

All: further to some feedback and potential confusion re: requirements and ranges referenced, I've compiled a table with 8 (4x2 variants per) functions that allows for the different permutations/possibilities of whether numeric/alpha characters are being entered/extracted.  If the actual requirement differs from what has been presented below- I'm throwing my towel in I'm afraid! ☺

PS-  for convenience, [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-EEn6HaGJe2aaCucf___DXZq6oHzQnjTJWUq2t7BAew/edit?usp=sharing) is the google sheet where you can find everything set out with functions and all (per screenshot below).

Ta / Peace.

[image]

Comment: James, thanks for your response, I use the wrong range in my inquiry. The range should  should be B2:J2 and could not get your info to work. However I did get some of to work. Example Row 2 (B2:J2) I was able to get a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i listed where I put the formula and letters b, f, & h were already posted in the puzzle and should not have been in the results. I was expecting a,c,d,e,h,i to be what was available. And just out of curiosity why do you use numbers instead of letters? I'm not closing this out yet, but maybe you will understand what I want.

Comment: He used numbers for the same reason you posted it in the start post

Comment: P.b. I took his example and put on a new sheet exactly like he has it and his abc's he has in cell B14 is what I am looking for, but the way he has it I have to enter numbers like he has in cell B4, and I am not entering numbers. I am enter letters from A to I and to need to know which abc's is missing from the abc's I have already entered.

Comment: That's not how you put it in your question

Comment: Hi - I'm assuming your original function works to your desired liking. RE: B2:J2 - I don't see the function changing much (if at all, i.e. besides referencing the specific cells that you are interested in)..  RE: entering letters instead of numbers - I'll update my post. If it's to your liking/meets the cause, consider voting accordingly - ta! :)

Answer (score 0):

Doing the substitution of letters for numbers seems to work fine here.  What kind of problem did you run into?  Did you perhaps neglect to put the quotation marks around the letters?

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(ISERROR(MATCH({"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"},B2:J2,0)),{"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"},""))
```

[image]

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld, above suggestions would not work, however, just so happens I figured it out myself and it's exactly like yours. How do I show this a solved and give you the credit?